# How a sequence of sentences is reported?

Tags: reported-speech

For example this.

> Jack: Federer will play against Nadal today. That will be their 4th
>   meeting on grass. Federer will probably win.

How that is reported?

> Jack said that Federer would play against Nadal today …

What is next?

Comment: I don’t understand your question. What are you trying to learn?

Comment: I meant how the above example would be constructed in indirect speech. What punctuation mark is followed after the 1st sentence? Then, how are the 2nd and the 3rd sentences added? Are all of them would be a part of the object of _said_ in _Jack said that ..._?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of "reported" speech is that you are describing what someone said. It is not a grammatical transformation, like changing active to passive. It is the difference between an object and me telling you about the object.

> Jack said that Nadal and Federer will meet for the fourth time on grass, and Federer is most likely to win.
>
> Jack said that Federer is probably going to beat Nadal when they meet on grass for the fourth time, later today.

So in these two equally acceptable descriptions of what Jack said, I have summarised, paraphrased and re-ordered for the sake of clarity and flow. I could have left the description in the same order:

> Jack said that Federer will play Nadal today. He said that it will be their 4th meeting on grass, and added that Federer will probably win.

So here I've chosen two different strategies. I've started a new sentence "He said..." and I've used a conjunction  "...and added ...". Again the reason for using different punctuation is to maintain clarity and flow. It would be correct but boring to say

> Jack said that Federer will play Nadal today. He said that it will be their 4th meeting on grass. He said that Federer will probably win.